# How to change background color in C#?

Tags: c#, background-color

I' have form that user can select a color. I'm writing that color to my database for use other forms too.

When I'm saving a color to database it's looks like this;

```
Color [A=255, R=255, G=128, B=64]
```

How can i convert this and use as background color?

Comment: which type of form windows or web form?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store the value from [`Color.ToArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toargb.aspx) in the database and [`Color.FromArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx) when you read from the database.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is a WinForms application use [`Color.FromArgb()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx):

```
BackColor = Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int A = 255; int R=255; int G = 128; int B=64;
System.Drawing.Color c = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb( A, R, G, B);
```

Answer (score 1):

I you write the color to the dbase as a string then you can use the ColorConverter class, ConvertToString() and ConvertFromString() methods.  Or you can store it as an integer, use the Color.ToArgb() and FromArgb() methods.